# How to return value from asynchronous function in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have recently started learning MEAN.  I have the following code to return collection of document of MongoDb.

```
var giveData = function()
{
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ngs'  



var retVal;  // this is a return value which will contain documents


mongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db)
                        {
                            if (err)
                            {
                                console.log(err)
                            }else
                            {
                                 db.collection('employees').find().toArray(
                                    function(err, doc)
                                    {
                                        if(err)
                                        { 
                                            throw err;
                                        }else{
                                            console.log(doc); // this works fine 
                                            retVal = doc;     // this does not assign the value ????  why so ??

                                        }

                                    }

                                );

                            }
                        }
                    )

console.log("Message from lib");                    
console.log(retVal);  // this returns undefined 
console.log("-----------------");

return retVal;  // this may return data from the server but is returning undefined 


}

 module.exports ={  showMessage: showMessage,
                        giveData: giveData
                    }
```

From the remarks it is clear that I want collection of documents from MongoDb database into a variable called retVal, which I have assigned value of doc on correct process.

Although the document is displayed successfully but somehow it does not get assigned to variable called retVal.

Please throw some light on the subject so that collection of document is returned from the function called giveData()

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section

```
var retVal;  // this is a return value which will contain documents
```

`retVal` is undefined

And at the bottom

```
return retVal;  // this may return data from the server but is returning undefined
```

`retVal` is still undefined because the call to `mongoClient.connect` is asynchronous

You're returning the **value** of `retVal` at a specific moment. This value will not change.

You should pass a callback function to `giveData` so you can access the returned data once it is received.

```
var giveData = function(callback) {
  var mongodb = require('mongodb');
  var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

  var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ngs' 

  mongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err)
    } else {
      db.collection('employees').find().toArray(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
          callback(err)
        } else {
          callback(null, doc)
        }
      })
    }       
  }

}

module.exports = {  
  showMessage: showMessage,
  giveData: giveData
}
```

And than use it like so

```
giveData(function(err, doc) {
  if(err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // you can now use doc!
  }
})
```

Comment: Your reply gives good focus.  Can you throw some light on callback(err) and callBack(null,doc)?  I think this will help me a lot to understand asynchronous NodeJs.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a node convention to handle callbacks. You used it yourself in `mongoClient.connect`. Basically the idea is that the first argument is always the error and it's the first thing you should check. If everything goes well and there's no error you send null to specify that there's no error hence the `callback(null, doc)`.

Comment: Thanks Yoni Levy.   But still I can not understand as to how do I return value from giveData() if there is no error.  Basically, what I want is I want to return a value from the function which should contain data from MongoDb.

Comment: I gave you a usage example. You need to pass a callback and in it check for an error first, if there's an error well then handle it the way you see fit. If there's no error you have the `doc` argument that contains the data you need. You should really read more about async operation and callback in js, this is basic stuff but there's too much to cover over here in the comments section.

Comment: @NizamuddinShaikh read this https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Comment: Async.js is used to orchestrate multiple asynchronous operations. I fail to see how is that related to this question.

Comment: Thanks Yoni Levy, it's a good link. Since then I have gone through a number of articles on web particularly as to how to handle asynch nature of JavaScript and I came across Async.js. Can you throw some light on using async.series or async.waterfall in this example? I shall appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: How do I use Asyn.js to return data from giveData()?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get more familiar with asynchronous flow of the Node.js - [this may help, for example](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-the-asynchronous-nature-of-nodejs--net-36183) .

Your bottom `console.log` and return happens **before** your assignment (`retVal = doc;`)

All the functions of mongoClient are asynchronous, and the returning should happen right after assignment (which happens after collection `employees` is fetched).

the code proceed to your current `return` without waiting the data from `db.collection('employees')`.

All code could be refactored to use node.js callback. Sure there are much mure elegant ways to solve it, but just to show you example.

```
   var retVal;
   function getEmployees(cb) {
        return mongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
             if (err) return cb(err);
             db.collection('employees').find().toArray(
                 function(err, doc){
                     if(err) return cb(err);
                     console.log(doc); 
                     cb(null,doc); 
                  });
          });
        }

 getEmployees((err, result) => {
      if (err) console.log('Error:',err);
      retVal = result;
      return retVal;
 });
```